# Need review of my solution. Calculating average days of open tickets

Tags: algorithm

First of sorry if I'm posting this question on a wrong forum, I know there are several ones for different kind of problems. My problem is concerning how to implement a solution to a problem, not problem with the actual code itself.

Imagine that you have a support system where users can submit tickets (much like a osticket system). The tickets can have multiple states such as "submittet/assigned" etc all the way until its "closed".

Now assume that you want the average number of days that tickets have been open (that is from its submitted until its closed). You want these numbers week by week. How would you solve this problem?

What I do is eqvivalent to the pseudo code below.

```
    Pick out all tickets that have ever existed and are in any state = alltheticketsarray
    for(var i =0; i<alltheticketsarray.length; i++){

    var weekarray = //determine which date that is smallest/largest and create an array containing all those weeks and weeks in between. Creating an empty object inside each index with the year-week as a key.
    }

    for(var i =0; i < alltheticketsarray.length; i++){
      var startdate = //picking out which date a ticket is submitted, converting it into a year-week number to know in which index in weekarray to start.
    var stop = //getting the week number when the ticket is closed, if not avaliable stop=weekarray.length

    for(var k =startdate; k < stop; k++){
    //add number of days the ticket has been open so far to weekarray, that is 
    number of days so far 
    add that number to  weekarray[k].opendays += convertToDays(weekarray[k] - weekarray[startdate])
    if(weekarray[k]===weekarray[startdate]){ 
        use moment.js to get which day number (1-7) the submittet value is and add hat value to weekarray[k].opendays
    }
    weekarray[k].opentickets++;
    }
}
```

Then to get the avarage days a ticket has been open for each week I take `weekarray[k].opendays/weekarray[k].opentickets`

Is this how you also would solve this problem? The reason I'm asking is because I keep getting unreasonable high values, like up to average of 70 days, and I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: First thing to do is to create an example on paper and verify if it is correct. If you can't tell if the result is correct then there is no way that we would be able to either.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your pseudocode, where it says

```
weekarray[k].opendays += convertToDays(weekarray[k] - weekarray[startdate])
```

This can't be right because, if I understand you code correctly, the convertToDays(...) expression calculates the number of days from startdate to the week 'k'.  However, you should be adding at most 7 to opendays for the week 'k' at this point in the loop (compare this with the next line that handles the first week when the ticket is open separately).

Most likely, you should have a similar special case for the last week as first the week.